# How can I compare two arrays with different length but they share the same values?

Tags: javascript

For Example:

```
let array1 = [3, 1, 2, 5];
let array2 = [1, 2, 3];
```

How can I compare the both arrays to get my output a boolean value?

Comment: what result do you expect? and why? what have you tried? what goes wrong?

Comment: compare what? order? values at positions? There's a bunch of comparisons you could do.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check if one array is a subset of another array then you could try something like this:

```js
let array1 = [3, 1, 2, 5];
let array2 = [1, 2, 3];

let isSubset = (arr1,arr2) => arr1.every(x=> arr2.includes(x));

console.log('Is array1 a subset of array2?',isSubset(array1,array2));
console.log('Is array2 a subset of array1?',isSubset(array2,array1));
```

Here first `console.log` returns false because not all elements of `array1` are present in `array2`.
But when we swap params inside `isSubset` function we now check if all of the elements of `array2` are present in `array1`. In this case we're getting `true` state.

Comment: what a genius , i was working in this tictactoe game for a while now and I stuck on how to detect the winner and now with your answer I can detect the winner , thanks a lot man